# Getting R rJava running on OSX El Capitan

Tags: java, r, macos, java-native-interface, rjava

I have been reading various solutions for the last 24 hours. They don't work for me.

I was trying to get a package `glmulti` installed in R. It wanted `rJava`.

That needed a version 6 (or is it 1.6) of Java, which was found as `javaforosx 2015-001`. I installed it. The instructions then suggested to reconfigure R using the command `sudo R CMD javareconf`, I ran into an error:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_65
Java home path   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
System Java on macOS

trying to compile and link a JNI program 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
detected JNI linker flags : -framework JavaVM
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
```

There are a lot of pages suggesting what to do but nothing works for me.

I looked at the suggestions from
http://conjugateprior.org/2014/12/r-java8-osx/
and thought that perhaps I should use java 8 from Oracle. Installed that as well.

What was odd was that after installation of java 8, the Java Control Panel on the System Preferences page said that I have java 1.8.0_121, and the path given was 
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java.

But if I do terminal command `/usr/libexec/java_home` I get

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and if I do `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` I get

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Other people claim that this command should have given the 1.8.0 path.

The test web page from Oracle claims that I do have 1.8.0 installed.
The command `java -version` claims that I am running

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

After all this, the first problem seems to be how to get a hold of `jni.h`?

If you need any more information, just ask.

Comment: Have you installed Java 8 JDK? JRE is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671

you can find there quite detailed explanation on how to deal with R, Java and rJava on macOS.

There are some steps you have to take to make the whole process go smooth.

Have fun with R and JNI!

Comment: .oOo. I love down voting without any comment in the morning ;) .oOo.